# Algebraic Notation for Circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, math-notation

When dealing with a circuit diagram of some type, a fairly typical procedure for simplifying the circuit is to redraw the circuit diagram a number of times, each time performing one or more independent atomic simplifications, such as combining series or parallel resistors, doing a source substitution, or other such things.

For instance, one might use this sequence of steps if one was asked to calculate the total current in this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faFCph.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sub>(One would then conclude that the total current is 2/3 amps.)</sub>

However, these successive diagrams are time- and space-consuming to draw.

Such a circuit could also, however, be represented using some sort of algebraic notation. For instance, something like "(R1 + (R2 | R3))". This could then be used with a set of production rules equivalent to the atomic substitutions used above:

```
1 Ω + (1 Ω | 1 Ω)
1 Ω + 0.5 Ω
1.5 Ω
```

While this simple off-the-top-of-my-head notation might not be able to represent every circuit topology, I would imagine that a more developed algebraic structure could be constructed to represent more complicated topologies (like some of the algebraic systems used for some things in graph theory). Even a more limited notation restricted to simple branching and such could be useful, though, as such systems are not uncommon.

I have searched online with Google for any some kind of established algebraic notation, but all the search queries I have attempted have only returned results regarding Boolean algebraic notation.

Is there any sort of existing notation or system like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often see || for "in parallel with".  At the end of the day, though, it can be represented as a mathematical formula, so that is what would normally be used.

For instance, your circuit would be written as:
$$
R1 + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R3}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any sort of existing notation or system like this?

Circuit simulation software often employs [netlists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlist).

[Here's](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_5/chpt_7/8.html) a list of examples, I'll report one:

[image]

```
v1 1 0 dc 24
v2 3 0 dc 15
r1 1 2 10k
r2 2 3 8.1k
r3 2 0 4.7k
.end
```

The notation is rather straightforward - `v1 1 0 dc 24`, for example, means "a voltage source `v1` from node `0`to node `1`, 24VDC".